# Number of Orbits of the action

Tags: group-theory

$G=GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ via matrix multiplication, I need to find the number of orbits of this action.

$\{Ax: A\in G\}$

I did some calculation and I think It has one orbit , I mean orbit of any non zero vector is whole $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I am not able to prove it.
Thank you for discussion

Comment: Given two non-zero vectors, construct an invertible matrix that sends one to the other. You also need to consider the orbit of the zero vector.

Comment: Then please consider answering the question yourself. This will have the double benefit of removing it from the unanswered list and giving you a chance to have people check if your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Orbit of $(1,0)^T$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

$A(1,0)^T=$ first collumn of $A$, suppose $x\in$ orbit of $(1,0)^T$ Then $x$ is the first collumn of some invertible matrix $A$ which is not $0$ or else $A$ would not be invertible. so orbit of $(1,0)^T$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Now let $\{y,z\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then  construct a matrix $A$ making collumn $y$ and $z$ must be invertible!

and $A(1,0)^T=y$ thus $y$ is in the orbit of $(1,0)^T$

Another orbiit is orbit of $(0,0)^T$

Comment: But this orbit is ${\mathbb R}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$. So there are two orbits in total.